# WebdriverWait won't work. Is there an alternative? (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I created a bunch of scrapers for this website. It has 39 pages to scrape, and I divided them by 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, and 31-39.

Here's my code for reaching those pages:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.forensicnurses.org/search/custom.asp?id=2100")

# Search in the USA
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txt_country"]'))
select.select_by_visible_text('United States')

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input')
search_button.click()


driver.implicitly_wait(8)
driver.switch_to.frame('SearchResultsFrame')

print('getting 11 to 20')
driver.implicitly_wait(8)
tab = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchResultsGrid"]/tbody/tr[26]/td/a[10]')
tab.click()

print('21-30')
driver.implicitly_wait(8)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SearchResultsGrid"]/tbody/tr[26]/td/a[11]')))
element.click();


print('31-39')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SearchResultsGrid"]/tbody/tr[26]/td/a[11]')))
element.click();
```

It never reaches 31-39. I'm able to make it reach 21-30 sometimes, but it usually stops at 11-20.

I get an error,

> .NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window

So is it just a case of luck? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: WebDriverWait doesn't seem to work for me when I specify the number of seconds inside the brackets - what I do instead is set a variable `timeout = 20` and then just do `WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)`. It may not work for you, but I found that to be the solution for me, so try that out.

Comment: Sounds like the frame you've put the driver in has closed.  (also, seting implicit wait will set it for the entire session...mixing implicit and explicit waits is not recommended. 
 They can conflict...)

Comment: You have mixed ; syntax in your code btw. Only the first .click() is right.

Comment: added the timeout variable, removed the implicit waits and removed the ; from the clicks, still not working :(

Comment: @Ira Villar Look at what I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that, try clicking on the `>` a tag and due to a request error, *429 Too many requests*, use *time.sleep()*.

```
driver.get("https://www.forensicnurses.org/search/custom.asp?id=2100")

#Search in the USA
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txt_country"]'))
select.select_by_visible_text('United States')

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input')
search_button.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.switch_to.frame('SearchResultsFrame')

print('getting 1 to 10')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#SearchResultsGrid > tbody > tr.DotNetPager > td > a:nth-last-of-type(1)')))
element.click()
time.sleep(10)

print('11-20')
*Repeat*

print('21-30')
*Repeat*

print('31-39')
*Repeat*
```

Another way would be this with an extra check for the last page:

```
while True:
    try:
        element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#SearchResultsGrid > tbody > tr.DotNetPager > td > a:nth-last-of-type(1)')))
        element.click()
        time.sleep(30)
    except Exception as e:
        break
```

Import

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```